# Add conversion constructor to specializaton of template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization, arithmetic-expressions

### Background

I am implementing a special-purpose container for numbers.

```
template <typename T>
class VectorBase
{
    // Some constructors...

    friend VectorBase<T> operator+(const VectorBase& a, const VectorBase& b)
    {
        VectorBase<T> res;
        // Addition...
        return res;
    }

    // Additional non-trivial logic...
}
```

It is then used for various types especially for double and float:

```
typedef VectorBase<float>    VectorFloat;
typedef VectorBase<double>   VectorDouble;
```

Now I would like to use a construct like this

```
VectorFloat  inFloat;
VectorDouble inDouble;

VectorDouble outDouble = inFloat + inDouble;
```

Where I want to guarantee that the addition operation is executed on `double` objects and not on `float` ones to avoid precision problems. Exactly as it is done in pure C expressions.

One way of achieving this is to first convert the `VectorFloat` object into `VectorDouble` and then perform the addition operation in the "double world". This can be done by hand (assigning the float variable into temporary double one) or automatically by the compiler into a temporary variable. To my knowledge, to do this, I need to have a parametric constructor or an assignment operator on the `VectorDouble` which takes an argument of type `VectorFloat` and does the actual conversion.

### Question

Is it possible to add a new parametric constructor to a specialization of a template without the need of replicating the whole template code for a specific template parameter?

```
VectorBase<double>::VectorBase<double>(const VectorBase<float> &b) { ... }
```

I know I can make a derived class which will contain the needed parametric constructor, but that will not work for me, since I need to derive another class from the `VectorBase` later on while still keeping it a template:

```
template<typename T>
class VerySpecialDerivedVector: public VectorBase<T> { ... };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with SFINAE, something like:

```
template <typename T2,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value
                                       && std::is_same<float, T2>::value>::type>
VectorBase(const VectorBase<T2> &) { /* .. */ }
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/v8yB0b).

but I think it would be better to have:

```
template <typename T1, typenale T2>
friend VectorBase<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>
operator+(const VectorBase<T1>& a, const VectorBase<T2>& b)
{
    using T = typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type;
    VectorBase<T> res;
    // Addition...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? I'll try to understand it and then I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: @ivokabel: [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) for the first one. type_traits for the second.

Comment: I chose to use the first suggestion because the second, although it solves the described problem nicely, causes problems later. Namely, it causes ambiguities when using expressions with basic types, e.g. `float len = ...; VectorBase<float> vec1; VectorBase<float> vec2 = vec1 / len;`.

Comment: PS: I would also like to vote your answer up, but my reputation is too low to do that.